# How to populate data in mongoose without changing current schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have already created two schema for mongoose named associates and outlets.
Outlet schema:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var OutletSchema = new Schema(
{
  associate_id: {type: ObjectId, max: 100 },
  city_id:{type:ObjectId, max: 100},
  outlet_name: {type: String, max: 100},
  oulet_address: {type: String, max: 500},
  outlet_contact: {type: String, minlength: 9, maxlength: 12 },
  active: {type: Boolean}`enter code here`
}`
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Outlet', OutletSchema);
```

Associate Schema:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AssociateSchema = new Schema(
{

  associate_name: {type: String, max: 100},
  associate_address: {type: String, max: 500},
  associate_contact: {type: String, minlength: 9, maxlength: 12 },
  associate_email: {type: String, max: 100},
  active: {type: Boolean}
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Associate', AssociateSchema);
```

these are my schema which i created.

How can i populate outlet in associates using relationship()

i have tried this code which is given below.

```
router.get('/getUsingPopulate', function (req, res) {
    data = {}
    Associate.relationship({path:'outlet', ref:'Outlet',refPath:'associate_id'})
    Outlet.find({}).populate('Associate').exec()
    .then(function(alldata){
        console.log(alldata)

    })


})
```

database of Associate:-

```
_id: 5b40428088e5f0187dedb342
category_id: 5b34a99709d3ff3e2b5a399c
associate_name: "Cafe Coffee Day"
associate_address: "Coffee day kormangala"
associate_contact: "989545458645"
associate_email: "ccdkor@yahoo.com"
active: true
__v: 0
```

database of outlet:-

```
_id: 5b4471f4c5bf8018409c7c64
associate_id: 5b40428088e5f0187dedb342
city_id: 5b3c49fee0de9210a60a2266
outlet_name: "Coffee Day Whitefield"
oulet_address: " Coffee Day Whitefield"
outlet_contact: "7587454478"
active: true
__v:0
```

Expecting output:-

```
  {
   "_id": "5b40428088e5f0187dedb342",
   "name": "Cafe Coffee Day",
   "outlets": [
     {
       "_id": "5b4471f4c5bf8018409c7c64",
       "associate_id": 5b40428088e5f0187dedb342,
       "name": "Coffee Day Whitefield",

     }]
```

Comment: You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation to populate **outlet** in **associates**  model

Comment: while using $lookup i got the result as "{"_pipeline":[{"$project":{"deal_on":"$deal_on"}},{"$lookup":{"from":"Outlet","localField":"outlet_id","foreignField":"_id","as":"OutletData"}}],"options":{}}"

Comment: You have to put your sample collection and the output to see how `$lookup` works

Comment: i'm trying to get all outlet details and associative details using associate_id. How can i join and get all details together.. please ref: above schemas and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your sample collection copying from robomongo or mongo shell then it will be easier for me to show you how `$lookup` works

Comment: please refer my collection. which given above

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer using this code:-

Outlet schema changed to :-

```
var OutletSchema = new Schema(
{
  associate_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Associate'  },
  city_id:{type:ObjectId, max: 100},
  outlet_name: {type: String, max: 100},
  oulet_address: {type: String, max: 500},
  outlet_contact: {type: String, minlength: 9, maxlength: 12 },
  active: {type: Boolean}
})
```

The code for populate which i gave is:-

```
Deal.find({..}).populate({
                                path: 'outlet_id',
                                model: 'Outlet',
                                populate: {
                                  path: 'associate_id',
                                  model: 'Associate'
                                }
                              }).exec()
```

Thanks for the support from everyone..